# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have only one application context file tradelc-servlet.xml. So I think ContextLoaderListener is not needed. But still I am getting the exception mentioned in the title

ClsEditBody.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="logic" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlc.tld" prefix="tlc" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld" prefix="c" %>


<%
    String titleKey="crp.cls.title." + request.getParameter("action");
%>
<c:set var="action">
         <%= (String)request.getParameter("action")  %>
</c:set>


<tlc:in parameter="action" value="modify;create">
    <form:form>
    <form:hidden path="ukey" />
.
.
.
.
```

web.xml

```
   <!--CharsetFilter start--> 

      <filter>
        <filter-name>Charset Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web.action.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
          <init-param>
            <param-name>characterEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
          </init-param>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Charset Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

  <!--CharsetFilter end-->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web.util.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Action Servlet Configuration -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>tradelc</servlet-name>
        <!-- Specify servlet class to use:
            - Struts1.0.x: ActionComponentServlet
            - Struts1.1:   ActionServlet
            - no Struts:   TilesServlet
        -->
        <!-- <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.tiles.ActionComponentServlet</servlet-class> -->
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- <servlet-class>com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web.action.DevlActionServlet</servlet-class> -->
        <!-- <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesServlet</servlet-class> -->

        <!-- Tiles Servlet parameter
            Specify configuration file names. There can be several comma
            separated file names
        -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>definitions-config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>


        <!-- Tiles Servlet parameter
            Specify Tiles debug level.
            O : no debug information
            1 : debug information
            2 : more debug information
        -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>definitions-debug</param-name>
            <param-value>1</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <!-- Tiles Servlet parameter
            Specify Digester debug level. This value is passed to Digester
            O : no debug information
            1 : debug information
            2 : more debug information
        -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>definitions-parser-details</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <!-- Tiles Servlet parameter
            Specify if xml parser should validate the Tiles configuration file.
            true : validate. DTD should be specified in file header.
            false : no validation
        -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>definitions-parser-validate</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>


        <init-param>
            <param-name>validate</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>


    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tradelc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    



    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>21</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- The Welcome File List -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web.exceptions.LockException</exception-type>
        <location>/errors/LockError.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <!-- Struts Tag Library Descriptor -->
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>


</web-app>
```

tradelc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web.actions" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="resources.application" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /cls/ClsEdit.jsp at line 12

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /cls/ClsEditBody.jsp at line 17

14: 
15: 
16: <tlc:in parameter="action" value="modify;create">
17:     <form:form>
18:     <form:hidden path="ukey" />
19:     <!-- OMX00003517 UAT: June 2009: Invalid Password JavaScript Issue   Start -->
20:     <input type="hidden" name="password1" value="">
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
    org.apache.jsp.cls.ClsEditBody_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(ClsEditBody_jsp.java:241)
    org.apache.jsp.cls.ClsEditBody_jsp._jspx_meth_tlc_005fin_005f0(ClsEditBody_jsp.java:214)
    org.apache.jsp.cls.ClsEditBody_jsp._jspService(ClsEditBody_jsp.java:155)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    org.apache.jsp.cls.ClsEdit_jsp._jspService(ClsEdit_jsp.java:87)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web.action.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:45)
```

Comment: How is your code supposed to work? What have you tried to tackle the problem so far?

Comment: I tried adding `ContextLoaderListener` to web.xml. But it gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml , it is obligatory!

Comment: There is also a annotation variant ;-)